# Sharing CocoaPods podspec data among multiple podspecs

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I am maintaining a multi-modular SDK. I am planning to map each SDK module (library, framework, etc.) to its own pod, hence the need to create/maintain multiple podspecs. However, there is some data/info that is common across all these podspecs. For example, I would like to maintain the same pod version (i.e. the SDK version) across all the pods. Or the sea set of targeted platforms, etc. All the pods' codabases are parts of the same git repo where each pod codebase "lives" in its own folder of the repo and all pods' folders are sibling folders to each other.
So, is there a way to create a "shared" podspec that could be "included/referenced" by each or some of the individual pod specs of the repo?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the shared podspec can be a dependency of the other pods. FirebaseCore.podspec and GoogleUtilities.podspec are examples in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

Comment: @Paull, thanks for the hint. However, as I understand the example above demonstrates how to define one pod as a dependency of the other, to make the dependent library buildable based on the dependency.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to have a file (a podspec or not) that defines a common set podspec parameters like 
  s.version          = '6.7.1'
  s.homepage         = 'http://fb.g.com'
  s.license          = { :type => 'Apache', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.authors          = 'G, Inc.'
that can then be reused/included/imported/referenced by multiple podspecs that need to share the same values.